# Whats the best way to include third party and custom JS files in Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, frameworks

I am new to Angular framework. Trying to convert plain HTML template into Angular project. Please suggest me the best way to include third party JS plugins like owl scripts and custom js scripts.

Comment: add inside angular-CLI scripts.

Comment: add js file path in index.html file and call JS plugin function from angular component ts file in ngOnInit method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dedicated library for angular for example:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-owl-carousel

To install this library, run:

> npm install ng2-owl-carousel --save